# how to prevent application auto start when phone boot up

Tags: android

I know that some apps register the BootComplete broadcast receiver to listen phone boot up action,I want to create a simple application to retrive those specified applications which register BootComplete receiver.Then is there any method to finish preventing those application auto start?Maybe android api doesn't supply some interfaces to finish this task,But maybe I can use another hack methods to make it true.So Does anyone know some interfaces or methods that can prevent app auto start?thanks:)

Comment: I don't want to install a app who developed by others,I want to how to creat a app which prevent application auto start,so I need the program method

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "android tuner" there you can see which apps receive the boot complete information. And you can also disable it there.